# How to prove the linear independence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $v_1,v_2 \space and \space v_3$ are linearly independent.

I have a function: $c_1v_1 + c_2(v_1+v_3) + c_3(v_2-v_1) = 0$

How can I show that $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0?$

Comment: You cannot, unless you know something about $v_i$'s.

Comment: I think I have to find some vectors v1,v2,v3 that can proof that. The question is how.

Comment: Any set of three linearly independent vectors will do.

Comment: It seems you are assuming that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent  and want to show that also $v_1$, $v_1+v_3$ and $v_2-v_1$. You should clarify that in your question.

Comment: @user yea that is correct. I apologize, i am new to linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, assuming that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent vectors, we have that

$$c_1v_1 + c_2(v_1+v_3) + c_3(v_2-v_1) = 0 \iff (c_1+c_2-c_3)v_1+c_3v_2+c_2v_3=0$$

and  we obtain

- $c_1+c_2-c_3=0$
- $c_3=0$
- $c_2=0$

that is $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ therefore also $w_1=v_1$, $w_2=v_1+v_3$ and $w_3=v_2-v_1$ are linearly independent vectors.

Comment: A naive question, do I have to provide vectors v1,v2,v3 to prove?

Comment: @Sachihiro The proof holds for any set of three given independent vectors.